# Let $v_1 = (1, 1, 0, 3)$, $v_2=(1,2,1,1)$ and $v_3 = (0,2,1,0)$ be in $\mathbb{R^4}$. What is the dimension of the subspace span$(v_1,v_2,v_3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $v_1 = (1, 1, 0, 3)$, $v_2=(1,2,1,1)$ and $v_3 = (0,2,1,0)$ be in $\mathbb{R^4}$. What is the dimension of the subspace $V=\text{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$?

Row reducing $[v_1^Tv_2^Tv_3^T]$ I get that $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ so the basis would be the set $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)\}$? which has size $3$?

Comment: You may arrive in a "simpler" form of a basis of $V$ when you row reduct $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ instead of their transposed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot deduce from what you wrote that that set is a basis of $V$. Actually, *none* of those vectors actually belong $V$. But it follows from what you did that the $3$ vectors are linearly independent and that therefore they form a basis of $V$, and that therefore $\dim V=3$.